# Jquery Async call issue CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, jquery, term-store

I am creating a custom Navigation using Termstore value. I am getting all term using JSOM like that

```
function getTermStores() {
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
var termStore = termStores.getByName("Taxonomy_7kHEf1rFgsI3590TSRk8rQ==");
var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("697accb5-3124-4704-bdee-c71b95825a1d");
terms = termSet.get_terms();
context.load(terms);
context.executeQueryAsync(first, function (sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
}

function first() {                     
       termList = "<div id='navigation'><div id='cssmenu'><ul>";       
       var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();                     
    while (termEnumerator.moveNext()) {         
        var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();            
        termList += "<li><a href='"+  currentTerm.get_localCustomProperties().URL +"'><span>" + currentTerm.get_name() + " </span></a></li>";           
        if (currentTerm.get_termsCount() > 0) { 
            second(currentTerm);
        }
        }
    }       
}


 function second(currentTerm) {
var termssecond = currentTerm.get_terms(); 
context.load(termssecond); 
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){       
var termEnS = termssecond.getEnumerator();              
termList += "<ul>";
       while (termEnS.moveNext()) {
        var scurrentTerm = termEnS.get_current();            
        termList += "<li><a href='"+  scurrentTerm.get_localCustomProperties().URL +"'><span>" + scurrentTerm.get_name() + " </span></a></li>";                     
    }  
}, function () { }); 

}
```

I am creating **Ul li** combination and render in page. 
My problem is when i try to get all TermSet using while loop and get it's sub term the script async call complete my while loop and get sub term later. so the html renders with wrong **UL li** combination.

Jquery differed is use full but i don't know how to use it. Please Help me.

Comment: Check if this helps you in understanding how to use deferreds/Promises Or Callbacks. http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2014/10/sharepoint-using-deferredspromises-or.html

Comment: How to check that number of terms or last element in while loop so i can return promise.